# one table dependencies on another table in redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

Can anybody let me know how to check table dependencies in amazon redshift ?
i.e i want to drop my master table and to list all other table which depends on my master table.

I am checking with below query but it is not working as required.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c_p.oid AS tbloid
,n_p.nspname AS schemaname
,c_p.relname AS NAME
,n_c.nspname AS refbyschemaname
,c_c.relname AS refbyname
,c_c.oid AS viewoid
FROM pg_class c_p
JOIN pg_depend d_p ON c_p.relfilenode = d_p.refobjid
JOIN pg_depend d_c ON d_p.objid = d_c.objid
JOIN pg_class c_c ON d_c.refobjid = c_c.relfilenode
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n_p ON c_p.relnamespace = n_p.oid
LEFT JOIN pg_namespace n_c ON c_c.relnamespace = n_c.oid
WHERE d_c.deptype = 'i'::"char"
AND c_c.relkind = 'v'::"char"
AND c_p.relname = 'TV_input source'
```

Any help is highly appreciated.